# Is there a sensor for finding if a particular file type is present in a Google cloud storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow, bucket, google-cloud-composer

I have a requirement in composer to poll a task till it finds a zip file in a bucket and run the subsequent tasks after the condition is met

The best i could get is GoogleCloudStoragePrefixSensor. But this is with prefix and doesn't work for this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to poll, then consider periodically (on a schedule) listing the files in the bucket and seeing which ones end with ".zip".  Alternatively, if you are willing to only accept new files that arrive, consider setting up a notification via PubSub such that when a new file arrives in the bucket, a function is executed which checks the file name.